# Get lastest values periodically in column

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example of my *pandas* based data:

```
print(df)
            country       cases
date    
2020-01-22  Austria         0    
2020-01-23  Austria         0    
2020-01-24  Austria         0
.... 
2020-05-31  Austria         0  
2020-06-01  Austria         1  
2020-06-02  Austria         0
2020-01-22  Belgium         0 
2020-01-2   Belgium         0        
...             ...        ..    
2020-05-29  United Kingdom  324  
2020-05-30  United Kingdom  215  
2020-05-31  United Kingdom  113  
2020-06-01  United Kingdom  556  
2020-06-02  United Kingdom  325
```

Here, for all of the different countries I would like to get the last 3 'cases' attribute's values.
For instance, for Austria it will be [0,1,0] and for UK it will be [113,556,325].

What is a good pythonic solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want them as a dataframe, you can do `groupby` and `tail` like:

```
df.sort_values(['country','date']).groupby('country').tail(3)
                   country  cases
date                             
2020-05-31         Austria      0
2020-06-01         Austria      1
2020-06-02         Austria      0
2020-05-31  United Kingdom    113
2020-06-01  United Kingdom    556
2020-06-02  United Kingdom    325
```

or if you want a list-like object:

```
(df.sort_values('date')
   .groupby('country').apply(lambda x: x['cases'].tail(3).tolist()))
country
Austria                 [0, 1, 0]
United Kingdom    [113, 556, 325]
dtype: object
```

Comment: maybe also `sort_values` before the `groupby` on `date` just in case

Comment: @dimitris_ps good point, on the first possible I also `sort_values` with country otherwise the result is mixed up between countries (more for presentation). in the second case sort_values by country does not really change the result

Comment: thanks. Since I need to retrieve a list [[0, 1, 0] ,..., [113, 556, 325]] I will add values[:] (df.sort_values('date').groupby('country').apply(lambda x: x['cases'].tail(3)).values[:]).tolist()

Answer (score 0):

```
# Read in CSV file-
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Convert 'date' column -
data.date = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])

# Print last 3 rows for 'cases' attribute-
for x in data.groupby('country'): 
    print(x[1].iloc[-3:, 2]) 

'''
3    0
4    1
5    0
Name: cases, dtype: int64
6    0
7    0
Name: cases, dtype: int64
10    113
11    556
12    325
Name: cases, dtype: int64
'''
```